# Serializing mutable objects in java

Tags: java, serialization

I am programming a networked turn based java game, and use the java serialization api to serialize the game state each time a player does a move.

To my annoyance, I discovered that the api assumes the objects are immutable. This means that each time I try to send the updated game state, the old game state is received at the clients.

Is there some way to make the objectoutput/objectinputstream forget that an object has already been sent and make a new object each time?

Comment: This doesn't sound right - can you post some sample code to show how you are serializing the object?

Comment: I know I'm not answering your question, but I'd avoid the serialization API and instead implement some higher-level, human-readable API. It'll save you time once you start to debug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectOutputStream.reset() is what you are looking for: [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29). It forces the stream to send updated objects.